# Error in loading Configuration Properties

Tags: spring-boot, consul

In my spring-boot 2 app I have application.yml as,

```
 limitsconf:
   limits:
     - api: PUBLISH
       valueType: REQUEST
       serviceName: default   
       time:
         HOURLY: 10
         MINUTE: 10000
```

My config class is,

```
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "limitsconf")
 public class DefaultRateLimitsConfig {
 private static final Logger logger = 
 LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultRateLimitsConfig.class);

 private List<DefaultLimit> limits = new ArrayList<>();

public static class DefaultLimit {
    String api;
    String valueType;
    String serviceName;
    Map<String,Long> time;

}

 }
```

The code works fine in local machine and all values are loaded as expected. 
But cloud env consul serializes yml file into environment variables so my configuration is represented as,

```
 key=limitsconf_limits value= [api:PUBLISH, valueType:REQUEST, serviceName:default, time:[HOURLY:10, MINUTE:10000]]
```

which is a string. I don't know which format consul represents/serializes values in. Now my DefaultRateLimitsConfig fails to load as it gives error,

```
 Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.List<DefaultRateLimitsConfig$DefaultLimit>]
```

How can I load the configuration in both the environment in a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0):

Got the reason and very bad workaround for it. The consul was storing application.yml values in an environmental variable named "limitsconf_limits". I was able to find it using env command. So according to external configuration of spring-boot https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html OS env variable got higher priority than yml file and hence the error "No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String]..." As OS env variable is a String.

Workaround was: I stored the value of the key as JSON string in yml file and parsed it using ObjectMapper class of the fasterxml.
But I don't know if there is any way to override Springboot's default behavior of priorities to load external configuration for specific configuration/class